# Parsing a gzip stream in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, mqtt

How can I unzip a gz stream in Node.js? I am trying to parse a gz stream (a data file ) using MQTT. My code looks like

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
, client = mqtt.createClient('1883','mqttserver');
client.subscribe('MQTT/#');
client.on('message', function(topic,message) {
var zlib  = require('zlib');
zlib.gunzip(message, function(err,message ) {
if (!err) {
console.log(message.toString());
}
});
```

Why is that whenever I receive a gz stream the data size is ~200 bytes smaller than the sent gz stream?

Comment: what is the error you encountered ?

Comment: nothing is printed in my console... but when i tried to write this data to file and unzip it throws the error     
gzip : invalid compressed data--format violated

Comment: did you double check the file is really a Gzip file ?

Comment: yes I did. I also reconfirmed it by using a MQTT - JAVA and C client to read the data. The data was fine then and I am able to read the file properly.I need a similar one to  java I used as i mentioned below:


InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getPayload());
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(in);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\log.c");
int len;
while((len = gzis.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
out.write(buffer,0,len);
}
gzis.close();
out.close();

Comment: The issue here is the difference in size of file sent and recieved. The gzip error is because of that. You should first check on recieving the full message first. The message that is sent is always a buffer/string not a stream. So can you check on it.

Comment: This problem happens only when i send a gz file not any other file. BTW could you please explain how can i check the full reception of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the library itself. The default encoding is set to string 'utf-8' hence the some data is missed. Please take a look at this
https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/issues/109

Thanks for all you quick responses